# Ruby on Rails server is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
C:\test-install>rails server

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
```

Comment: What is your question? Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: my question is when i enter rails server command then this error is showing up instead of giving me the details of localhost url

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have the 'uglifier' gem installed.  Was this gem included in your Gemfile, and have you installed the bundle?

Comment: It should already be added to your Gemfile if you used rails new 'project-name'.  All you need to do is type "bundle install" in the terminal while in your project directory, and it should install all the gem files you need to run rails.

Comment: now its saying the system can not find the path specified